# WPF DataGrid - get items from column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm looking for a simple way to retrieve all items in a specific column of a WPF DataGrid. I have both the DataGrid, DataGridColumn and DataGridColumnHeader as a reference, but I can't seem to find a logical way of getting the elements.

Using the Header property of the DataGridColumn is not an option as I'm using a custom Header object in some cases.

Comment: datagrid should be bind to come structured collection... like ObservableCollection<MyDataClass>... you should not use header, just get the instance of MyDataClass of specific row and use the getter of required property

Comment: I'm preparing a generic control, not a specific case. And for that, I need not know which property is bound to the specific column. I'm looking for a generic solution that will return the values in a datagrid, in a specific column, after supplying it both the dg and the dgc.

Comment: and how do you tell the control which header should be shown for which property? I would start with that then

Comment: Have you tried to bind the content from the grid to a observable list in a one way bind ?

Comment: I can't edit the DataContext, this must be done completely locally, in the UserControl I created for the whole thing (which is in turn inserted into the DataGriColumnHeader Template). The columns are defined manually within the XAML, but as I said, this is a control which MUST work in a generic way. If it was a single usage thing, I'd hardcode the whole shebang, but alas I can't.

Comment: This is probably not possible because by default DataGrids use Virtualization, meaning it only draws the items it needs to display on screen and when scrolling, it just replaces the data for each item. For example, if your grid has 1000 items, but only 20 can be displayed at a time, it will only render about 24 rows (extra for scroll buffer), and replace the data behind each row as you scroll. What are you actually trying to do with the column data? There is probably a better way of accomplishing your task.

Comment: I'm trying to create a list of distinct items in the given column, to create an Excel-like filter.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty straight forward to do that if you already have an instance of the DataGrid. Here is a simple extension method you can use to get an enumerable of all items in column of DataGrid.

```
namespace Extensions
{
    public static class DataGridExtension
    {
        public static IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> GetItemsInColumn(this DataGrid dg, int col)
        {
            if (dg.Columns.Count <= col)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Column " + col + " is out range, the datagrid only contains " + dg.Columns.Count + " columns.");
            foreach (object item in dg.Items)
            {
                yield return dg.Columns[col].GetCellContent(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then to call the method you can just do,

```
dg.GetItemsInColumn(colNumber);
```

Comment: If you bound the DataGrid, then `dg.Items` will return you the collection of your items, not the actual `DataGridRow`. If you want the actual UI element for each item, I believe you'll need to use the `ItemContainerGenerator` to obtain the UI element associated with each item, but even that probably won't work correctly if Virtualization is turned on (default) since UI items are re-used, while only the Data changes.

Comment: Rachel, you would want to bind to dg.ItemsSource not directly to items. Items will contain a list of items used to generate the content, which is fine since GetCellContent is overloaded for that purpose. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.getcellcontent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Hrm perhaps I am mistaken and DataGrid is different, but I thought with other controls for displaying lists of items (TabControl, ListBox, ComboBox, etc) the `.Items` property returns the list of bound items, not the actual UI items. I would need to run a test with DataGrid to verify if DataGrid works the same way or not, but I suspect it would. Also, the same point about Virtualization would apply which is another reason why I think this.

Comment: You are correct in that it would return a list of bound items, it is the GetCellContent method that returns the UI content of the cell. I think you are right about virtualization as it would reuse the elements on the screen but that can be turned off,

Comment: Oh you're right, I'm not sure what I was thinking when I started this comment chain. I [looked it up](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.getcellcontent(v=vs.110).aspx) and `GetCellContent` does work with the actual data object, and not just the `DataGridRow` object. So this probably would work, possibly with virtulization too. Would need to test to make sure. I would not recommend disabling it though due to performance reasons for large grids.

Comment: The only issue with this code sample is, that it will only return values IF the item is on-screen. If it isn't, the value will simply become null (because GetCellContent will not return disposed items' children).

Comment: @fonix232, yeah that is expected if the datagrid virualization is on, but it is also correct since there is no content to get hence why it returns null so, it isn't really an issue just a feature. If you need all the cells to be created you will have to turn off virtualization on the DataGrid by setting the `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing` property to false.